# How to change the UID of a user with an encrypted home directory

Tags: users, ecryptfs

How can I change the UID of a user with an encrypted home directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to logout the user you want to modify and kill all processes he runs.
A good approach is to restart and log in as root or as another `sudo` user.

To enable the root user execute the following commands.

```
$ sudo su
# passwd
```

Now you can log in using root and the password you provided.
Once logged in as root execute

```
# usermod -u newUID myuser
```

to change myuser's uid and

```
# chown -R myuser /home/.ecryptfs/myuser
```

to change the owner of the encrypted files.
You should now be able to log out and log back in as myuser.